# a+b+c=3 prove $\frac{a^2}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2+a^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+a^2}+\frac{27}{2}\ge3(a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc)$

Tags: inequality

[Original post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4t243f4h2754290_nice_and_not_easy_ine)

> Let $a,b,c\ge0: ab+bc+ca>0$ such that: $a+b+c=3.$ Prove that: $$\frac{a^2}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2+a^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+a^2}+\frac{27}{2}\ge3(a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc)$$

This is very nice symmetrical inequality. I failed after using Nesbit inequality because: $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc\leq5$ does not hold for all. For example $(a,b,c)=(0,6;0,9;1,5)$ Maybe C-S help: $$\frac{a^2}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2+a^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+a^2}\ge\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)}$$ then I use pqr but it is very complicated.

Is there any help to full of my idea or other better ones? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Both the LHS and the RHS are  functions on the compact set $a+b+c=3$,all coordinates positives (we should add the valu $+\infty$ for $(3,0,0), (0,3,0),(0,0,3)$. It is enough to check that the minimum of the LHS is greater than the max of the RHS.

In fact both are acheived at the point $A=(1,1,1)$, where $LHS(A)=15$ and $RHS(A)=15$

To check this assertion, we use Lagrange multiplier method, let $f(a,b,c)$ , then the Lagrange equation is
$\nabla f=\lambda (1,1,1)$
or ${\partial f\over \partial a }={\partial f\over \partial b }={\partial f\over \partial c }$ and $a+b+c=1$

For the RHS, and find $a+bc=b+ac=c+ab, a+b+c=1$ whence $a=b=c$

The LHS is more tricky, however the function is homogeneous, and instead we study the function $F(x,y,z)= {x\over y+z}+{y\over x+z}+{x\over x+y}$ on the e cone $x,y,z >0$.

The  restriction of $F$ to $x+y+z=1$ this function is ${x\over 1-x}+{y\over 1-y}+{z\over 1-z}$, and Lagrange says
${1\over (1-x)^2}={1\over (1-y)^2}= {1\over (1-z)^2}$, so that $x=y=z$.

Of course, a point if to check that this is actuallt a min, but the function is proper therefore admits a minimum, and the critical point is unique, so it is a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the -1 vote. Is there a mistake somewhere in this argument ?